# Locking file for writing from Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, file-locking

I want to lock a file for writing from a Windows Service, but so far my attempts to obtain a lock are not working. The same code works from a Console Application, though.

From what I've read, this is because [opportunistic locking](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296264) is not enabled for my service.

How can I prevent a file from being written to by locking it from a service without resorting to registry hacks?

### Code to lock:

```
FileStream lockStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

### Code to unlock:

```
lockStream.Close();
lockStream.Dispose();
```

Comment: Are you locking the same file or different files?

Comment: I've tried `FileStream.Lock`, but that blocks writing and reading and doesn't work from my service either.

Comment: what code are you using that works from a console app?

Comment: @Kane: It's just one file I want to prevent the system from writing to.

Comment: What's the error?  I would not have thought that config mods were needed to make this code work.

Comment: @Steve: There is no error, but I am able to write to the text file in question from notepad after attempting a lock from my service. The same code blocks writing when not running in my service.

Comment: I cannot see how this code prevents others from sharing the file.  See @Shiv's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  using (fs = new FileStream("somefile.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
  { }
```

Have you used the FileShare mode when you open the file for reading or writing?

Comment: Just tried it. I can still write to the file from other applications.

Comment: @FreshCode: Are you sure it is the _same_ file? A service has a different working directory.

Comment: @Henk: Yes. It's a system file.

Comment: @FreshCode have you tried this with just a regular file instead of a system file (whatever that means). I've used this from ASP.NET and IIS which essentially runs as a service and it works as expected.

Comment: To clarify, I don't want to lock the file for a short while. The file should be locked until further notice, so I am not using a "using (...)" statement, I am storing my FileStream.

Comment: Solved by making sure there is a reference to the fileStream and that it is refreshed after a write or a read.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Global Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) being very careful to release it (Finally etc.)

Comment: I want to stop other processes from writing to a file. A mutex won't help unless other processes wait on the mutex.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I erroneously assumed that you only wanted to protect from your own processes (as only you know the filename)